# How to use existing session with Seleniumbase?

Tags: python, selenium, session, seleniumbase

I would like seleniumbase to use my existing session when it launches vs starting a clean one.

How do I start selenium using an existing session?

webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=option)
```

UPDATE:

This is marked as a duplicate which it is not.

> Dear @TodorMinakov this code here didn't meet my expectations. I wanted whenever I run the python program to select the unique opened window and use selenium over that window. I will appreciate your help. – Youssof H

Same issue here. The referred URL does not grab an existing session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use default chrome profile.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=PATH") #)PATH is path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

To find path to your chrome profile data you need to type chrome://version/ into address bar.
For ex. mine is displayed as C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default,

If path will not work, try to remove \Default\ so we end up with only C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data.

Better to copy-paste default profile outside, because there no way to use same session (cookies) in two browsers in same time.

Comment: I get an "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: failed to write prefs file" error.